# How bind a key to execute a tmux command in Vim Normal mode?

Tags: vim, tmux

I use the tmux terminal multiplexer and I have this simple layout:

[image]

I have a Vim pane for code editing and a terminal for building and searching the code and other stuff.

As you may know when I'm in Vim pane I can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd> to zoom the Vim pane and press it again to zoom back to the original layout.

Now I want to know whether it's possible to bind <kbd>Esc</kbd> in Vim's Normal mode to send <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd> to zoom the Vim pane?

Something like other IDEs that pressing <kbd>Esc</kbd> will hide everything except the code editor?

Comment: @Marth Yeah, You are right, but it's ok. Pressing `Esc` will toggle zoom state of the panes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `:!<cmd>` from vim to pass `<cmd>` to the shell, so:

```
:!tmux resize-pane -Z
```

will toogle the zoomed state of vim's pane.
Then you just have to remap `Esc`:

```
:nnoremap <Esc> :!tmux resize-pane -Z<CR><Esc>
```

---

This however will toogle the zoomed state every time you press `Esc` (hence actually revealing other panes half the time).

I'm guessing you want vim to stay maximize, so (credits to [this post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/184255/80308) for identifying if a pane is zoomed):

```
:nnoremap <Esc> :silent! exec "!if \\! tmux list-panes -F '\\#F' \\| grep -q Z; then tmux resize-pane -Z; fi"<CR>:redraw!<CR><Esc>
```

Comment: @saeed: It should be fixed now (I use zsh and I didn't test the command against sh).